# Colab with CUDA 8.0 returns GPU not found error

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm currently trying to run some code using Colab's GPU. The problem is that I have to use Tensorflow-GPU 1.4, which requires CUDA 8.0 and cudnn v6. I'm installing the right version of CUDA and cudnn using this code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)

!apt update -qq;
!wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/Prod2/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64-deb; 9
!dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64-deb;
!apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/7fa2af80.pub;
!apt-get update -qq;
!apt-get install cuda gcc-5 g+±5 -y -qq;
!ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-5 /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc;
!ln -s /usr/bin/g+±5 /usr/local/cuda/bin/g++;
!apt install cuda-8.0;

!dpkg -i "/content/drive/My Drive/libcudnn6_6.0.21-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb"
!ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.6*
```

Then I try to check for the GPU using:

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow -y
!pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu -y
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.4
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random
import os
import sys
import argparse
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
from PIL import Image
import imutils

os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "2"
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))
```

But it always returns the error saying that the GPU wasn't found:

```
SystemError  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-824c0cfcdb97> in <module>()
     19 device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
     20 if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
---> 21   raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
     22 print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))
     23 

SystemError: GPU device not found
```

Do you know how can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you change the runtime type to GPU and confirm GPU is available ?

Comment: Yup, already switched to GPU

Comment: Turns out that Colab doesn't support Python 2 anymore. That _could_ be it.